# SD card partitioning confusion

Tags: partitions

I don't get this statement:

Choose "File System: ext2" if you plan to use App2SD for app storage, or choose "File System: swap" if you plan to use a swap file to extend your Android's RAM using the card

What If I want to have both storage and swap... is which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, if you want both storage and swap, you need only partition your SD card with both. After wiping your SD card, you would make a FAT partition (or FAT32 if the SD card is 4GB+). Then you create the ext2 partition. If you want to use a swap partition as well, just remember to leave some of the card for it. Then create a third "swap" partition.
ex. for a 32GB SD card, one might make an 8GB FAT32 partition, then a 16GB ext2 partition and finally an 8GB "swap" partition.

Check this link for more/better explanation. 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/SD_card_partitioning